# Division of numbers in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new at Android Studio. I have copied code from a youtube tutorial same to same. After executing, this error appears: "Operator '/' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'double'"
Following is the code. Please identify the problem.

```
   23 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   24
   25        public void buttonConvert (View view){
   26        EditText amountRupees = findViewById(R.id.amountRupees);
   27            String PKR=amountRupees.getText().toString();
   28            Double doubleRupees=Double.parseDouble(PKR);
   29            Double doubleDollar = PKR/200.45;
   30            String toastText="="+doubleDollar.toString()+"$";
   31       Toast.makeText(this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   32    
   33        }
```

Comment: `I have copied code from a youtube tutorial` i understand you're learning, but try to make sense of what you're copying and what you're doing as you go, don't just say that something is the same as the code you've seen so it must work, you'll learn more by actually checking if what you've done makes sense

Answer (score 1):

At line 29 you are trying to divide a String by a double. You can try to parse the String into a double so you can divide it:

```
Double doubleDollar = Double.parseDouble(PKR)/200.45;
```

Comment: Be aware that this will throw an exception if the EditText is blank or has non-numeric text in it.